# In the same sql task of ant, is it possible to provide different transaction behaviors for different transactions?

Tags: ant

```
<target name="create-db-tables" depends="initialize">
        <fail message="Missing property [datasource.url]." unless="datasource.url" />
        <fail message="Missing property [db.user]." unless="db.user" />
        <fail message="Missing property [db.password]." unless="db.password" />
        <fail message="Missing property [db.sql.driver]." unless="db.sql.driver" />
        <sql driver="${db.sql.driver}" url="${datasource.url}" userid="${db.user}" password="${db.password}" output="${basedir}/createTable.log" onerror="continue">
<classpath>
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/../lib/ojdbc.jar"/>
</classpath>
            <transaction src="${basedir}/ddl/dropTables.sql" />
            <transaction src="${basedir}/ddl/createTables.sql" />
        </sql>
</target>
```

I have above target defined in my ant script, which drops the tables first and then creates them. I want ant to ignore the errors when dropping the tables (i.e. onerror="continue"), but to throw exception (i.e. onerror="abort") on error occurred during table creation. But it takes the transaction behavior in the "sql" tag and hence it is common for all the transactions.

I don't want to create separate sql tags and repeat the DB details. Also, I want to execute sql through files. How can I do it through ant?

Comment: whats so bad about repeating the sql tag?

Comment: I'm not liking to give those DB attributes twice. Is there any way to overcome that? I'd not mind using sql tag twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do it like this:

1. create an sql tag for each segment you need, just reuse the properties you giv (this may look ugly and duplicated but works)
2. define the classpath prior to the sql tag and reuse it via `classpathref`

It could look like this:

```
<target name="create-db-tables" depends="initialize">
        <fail message="Missing property [datasource.url]." unless="datasource.url" />
        <fail message="Missing property [db.user]." unless="db.user" />
        <fail message="Missing property [db.password]." unless="db.password" />
        <fail message="Missing property [db.sql.driver]." unless="db.sql.driver" />

        <classpath id="ojdbcpath">
             <pathelement location="${basedir}/../lib/ojdbc.jar"/>
        </classpath> 

        <!--- First Drop -->
        <sql driver="${db.sql.driver}" url="${datasource.url}"
            userid="${db.user}" password="${db.password}"
            output="${basedir}/createTable.log" onerror="continue"
            classpathref="ojdbcpath">
            <transaction src="${basedir}/ddl/dropTables.sql" />
        </sql>

        <!--- Then create -->
        <sql driver="${db.sql.driver}" url="${datasource.url}" 
            userid="${db.user}" password="${db.password}" 
            output="${basedir}/createTable.log" onerror="abort" 
            classpathref="ojdbcpath">
            <transaction src="${basedir}/ddl/createTables.sql" />
        </sql>
</target>
```